# ¿Cómo forzar a https ingresando con www.midominio.com?

Tags: apache, ssl, aws

Que regla debería poner para que si se ingresa:
www.midominio.com
midominio.com
a: https
tengo certificado de amazon

no consigo hacer que redireccione a https en mi archivo bitnami.conf, actualmente lo tengo asi, pero si ingreso **www.midomimio.com** no redirige a **https** sino a **http**

```
DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs"
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://www.midominio.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: ¿Cuentas con tu certificado de segurdiad?

Comment: amazon web services

Comment: Bueno no se si cuentas o no con el, te dejo un link donde explica cómo instalar el certificado de seguridad en Apache https://www.digicert.com/es/instalar-certificado-ssl-apache.htm

Comment: El certificado ya está instalado sólo que no redirige únicamente desde www

Comment: Al menos en la configuración que muestras no veo nada cómo: `SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /ruta/a/su_dominio.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /ruta/a/su_dominio.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /ruta/a/DigiCertCA.crt`

Answer (score 0):

Lo mismo llego un poco tarde y lo conseguiste, pero para otras personas puede venir bien esta info.

Lo que voy a poner es para Apache 2.4 y te redirecciona todo el trafico que entre por http al puerto https.

## Redireccion de todo el trafico a HTTPS

```
# Forzar que no se procese ninguna peticion por HTTP
<Location /*>
    SSLRequireSSL
</Location>


RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !HTTP/1\.1$
RewriteRule .* - [F]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [L,R]
```

De todas formas, si estás en AWS y tienes balanceador "Classic", entre el "Listener port" y el "Listener Instance", puedes hacer la redirección de entrada al 80 por el 443.

En los nuevos balanceadores de aplicación, es un poco mas complicado y no lo he probado.

Un saludo.